# Obtaining TV Listing / Guide Data

Tags: listings, television

Does anyone know how to programmatically obtain TV listings for a particular time zone?  Is there a service I can subscribe to?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked with the content providers?  I.e., the TV networks and cable channels.  It seems that they would provide this information.  Have you checked **any** of their web sites for listing information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TV guide listing API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886302/tv-guide-listing-api)

Comment: TV Rage provides a [free API][1] for TV listings. 


  [1]: http://services.tvrage.com/

Answer (score 0):

Searching for [TV Listings API](http://www.google.com/search?q=tv+listings+api) has a lot of promising results, but I don't think you're going to find any free ones, for better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cable provider or try to scrape off their sites?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I searched, the only viable solution I've found is this one :

http://services.tvrage.com/

They provide a public API that is quite complete and updated regularly, but it's not timezone dependant.

I'm afraid that what you are asking is too specific.
Maybe you should create it yourself ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could contact the team behind Zapping.io. They have an API for the television programming with metadata (actors, plot, posters and ratings)

http://www.zapping.io