# TV guide listing API

Tags: api, listings, television

Does anybody know a provider offering TV listings (through API or download) for all channel and cable providers?

Or is there any independent company collecting/providing such data?
An API/REST/SOAP interface would be great.

Comment: For what country/region?

Comment: TVRage has a good API http://services.tvrage.com/info.php?page=main I have an example with full source for working with the API in C# here: http://www.jarloo.com/sojurn-the-tv-app/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The MythTV folks have gathered [resources for various countries here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/XMLTV).  If you're in the US or Canada, they recommend the [Schedule Direct](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Schedules_Direct) service.

These services are generally based on the [XMLTV](http://wiki.xmltv.org/index.php/Main_Page/) data format/toolset.

Comment: TV Rage is excellent and, unlike Schedule Direct, free. http://services.tvrage.com/

Comment: TV Rage works well. Got a Github project that uses it if your looking for an example. https://github.com/kelias/Jarloo.Sojurn

Comment: TV Rage has been shutdown. So, route your requests through http://www.tvmaze.com/api

Answer (score 10):

Rovi offers both SOAP and REST APIs for TV listings. It supplies listings for all channels of the cable, satellite, and broadcast services in multiple countries. Rovi is the source the cable companies use. See this [website](http://developer.rovicorp.com).

Answer (score 8):

Schedule Direct doesn't grant commercial licenses.  I'm checking out tvrage as mentioned above and [Rovi](http://developer.rovicorp.com/) right now.

Edit:  If this is a commercial project, I recommend contacting Tribune Media Services (click "License our Content" in the footer at [Zap2It.com](http://www.zap2it.com/)).  That was the solution I chose for my company, simply because they were much more prompt in their response than Rovi.  The paid listings are XML files.

If all you need is a non-commercial license, SchedulesDirect works very well.  If you have questions about their licensing, they encourage you to ask.  We started using their listings and then had to change tack because of licensing issues.

Comment: For getting schedules for commercial purpose which one is better??

Comment: We ended up going with Tribune Media Services- however this was almost 4 years ago now :)  I'd encourage you to look around and see if there's anything more modern / well-documented available out there.  Good luck, and please report back with your findings if you come across something better!  I think it would help a number of other folks as well.

Comment: I found following API providers on internet: Tribune Media Services at - http://developer.tmsapi.com , Rovi Cloud Services at -http://developer.rovicorp.com/

Comment: FYI, Tribune bought Gracenote, so that's who handles their data now. The link just above here forwards there.

Answer (score 3):

You could contact staff of [WebTelevideo](http://www.webtelevideo.com) at info@webtelevideo.com that has solved your problem. They may provide you an account to their own API.

WebTelevideo API has TV Scheduling for many countries and metadata (actors, directors, plot, trailers, posters etc..)