# Looking for an RSS feed for Electronique Program Guide (EPG)

Tags: xamarin, rss, mobile-application, epg

I'm looking to create a mobile app in which I will be needing the EPG of preferably every channel that exists.  That case may be too good to be true so what I'm looking for now is an RSS feed from which I can constantly get the EPG of some, let's say, well known channels.  Can anyone help me on where/how to get this?

Comment: this kind of data is probably only available by subscription

Comment: what kind of subscription (i'm looking for a big database containing too many channels and any web service would do not only an RSS feed)

Comment: I mean this data is not going to be available for free.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886302/tv-guide-listing-api